# Is there any way to update only one cell record in MongoDB using nodes and express js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I want to update only one record of the mongoDB data
For example in the given data below i want to update the value of CAD

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("615564fbab33d4da1ab2d9bb"),
    AUD: 20,
    CAD: 92.8,
    CHF: 69.14,
    EUR: 63.03,
    GBP: 54.22,
    KWD: 22.49,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

So what will be the query of updating its record and i am getting two inputs from frontend

```
var doc= {
  TNAME:req.body.tname,
  TVALUE:re.body.tvalue
  }
```

The TNAME here is CAD, and TVALUE will be its updated value.
On frontend, the code is like

```
 var doc={tname,tvalue};
  
    axios.put('/memfeeput', doc)
    .then( res => {
      alert('Updated successfully!');
     }   
    )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.response);
      alert('An error occurred! Try submitting the form again.');
    });
```

where in code `var doc={tname,tvalue};`, the tname and tvalue are the usestates i.e.

```
 const [tname, setname] = useState("");
  const [tvalue, setvalue] = useState("");
```

How the query should be written in order to access the CAD/ or any other particular array record.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a update query, and set update key in `[tname]` in object,

use `updateMany` for updating multiple documents, for single document update you can use `updateOne` methods,

```
let result = await MemberFee.updateOne(
  { _id: _id }, 
  { $set: { [req.body.tname]: re.body.tvalue } }
);
```

Comment: MemberFee.updateOne({_id: _id}, { $set: { [req.body.tname]: req.body.tvalue } }).then
 {
   res.send("success")
 } tried this code but the update didn't successful

Comment: The {_id: _id} i am writing for matching the id and then updating CAD record

Comment: what is the response from query? and did you added `await` before query?

Comment: It works now with this code : MemberFee.findOneAndUpdate({_id: _id}, {$set:{[doc.TNAME]:req.body.tvalue}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});